# running exe makes system unresponsive

Tags: windows-server-2008, executable, chkdsk

I run the file using the command prompt and it got stuck and we had to reboot the server.

After  the server started I put the exe into another folder and when I run this time it run sucessfully but it still hung when we run it from the original folder.

All this suggested that there may either be a problem with the disk or that some other process was interfering. I also noted that when opening the original folder from the windows explorer, the progress bar that shows the folder loading (in the address bar) never completes to show the folder is loaded completely.

The **chkdsk /r** doesnt show any errors.

Please analyze the causes.

Comment: what .exe? Some more detail may help.

Comment: if you open a cmd shell and navigate to that directory can you do a directory listing? Are there any DLL's in there, any chance that they look like system DLL's?

Comment: the exe is part of our application. It is a stand alone application.

Comment: i can do the listing of the directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, running a virus scan fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend downloading and running the free Process Monitor tool http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx.  Run Process Monitor and add your executable's name (e.g. myprogram.exe) as a "Process Name" filter.

Then, run your program and Process Monitor will show all file system I/O and registry activity for it.  Look at the Process Monitor output at the time your program fails - you may be able to see some failures which give you a hint as to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the folder and recreate.  Does the exe interact with the folder in anyway?  Maybe a permissions issue on the folder itself.